# output files (chromosomal chunks) merging in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have a nextflow process that produces multiple chunks for each chromosomes into a channel, say, `imputation` which looks like,

```
chr1.imputed.chunk1.gen.gz chr1.imputed.chunk2.gen.gz chr1.imputed.chunk3.gen.gz 
chr1.imputed.chunk1.stats chr1.imputed.chunk2.stats chr1.imputed.chunk3.stats
chr1.imputed.chunk1.bgen chr1.imputed.chunk2.bgen chr1.imputed.chunk3.bgen
.....
```

There are many chunks for each chromosome (22 chromosomes). How can I effectively merge them
to respective chromosomes for each type of file set to get,

```
chr1.imputed.merged.gen.gz
chr1.imputed.merged.stats
chr1.imputed.merged.bgen
```

After getting the merged output, I would like to delete all the chunks. Any help?

The actual code that generate those chunks are:

```
process imputation {
publishDir params.out, mode:'copy'
input:
tuple val(chrom),val(chunk_array),val(chunk_start),val(chunk_end),path(in_haps),path(refs),path(maps) from imp_ch
output:
tuple val("${chrom}"),path("${chrom}.*") into imputed
script:
def (haps,sample)=in_haps
def (haplotype, legend, samples)=refs
"""
impute4.1.2_r300.3 -g "${haps}" -h "${haplotype}" -l "${legend}" -m "${maps}" -o "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}" -no_maf_align -o_gz -int "${chunk_start}" "${chunk_end}" -Ne 20000 -buffer 1000 -seed 54321

if [[ \$(gunzip -c "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}.gen.gz" | head -c1 | wc -c) == "0" ]]
then 
 echo  "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}.gen.gz" is empty
else
 qctool_v2.0.8_rhel -g "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}.gen.gz" -snp-stats -osnp "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}.snp.stats"
 qctool_v2.0.8_rhel -g "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}.gen.gz" -og "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}.bgen" -os "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk${chunk_array}.sample"
fi
 """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the following lines of code resolved the issue.

```
imputed.into{impute_bgen;impute_gen;impute_sample;impute_stat}
bgens=impute_bgen.groupTuple().transpose().map{chrom,bfiles -> tuple(chrom,bfiles[0])}.groupTuple()
gens=impute_gen.groupTuple().transpose().map{chrom,bfiles -> tuple(chrom,bfiles[1])}.groupTuple()
samples=impute_sample.groupTuple().transpose().map{chrom,bfiles -> tuple(chrom,bfiles[2])}.groupTuple()
stats=impute_stat.groupTuple().transpose().map{chrom,bfiles -> tuple(chrom,bfiles[3])}.groupTuple()
```

Answer (score 2):

You had this

```
output:
tuple val("${chrom}"),path("${chrom}.*") into imputed
```

With that output channel specification from before, you might have to do something like this in a downstream `process`

```
input:
tuple val(name), path(chr_files) from imputed

script:  
gen_files = chr_files.findAll { it.toString().endsWith('.gen.gz') }.sort()
stat_files = chr_files.findAll { it.toString().endsWith('.stats') }.sort()
"""
# try with echo first to see if you get what you want
echo ${gen_files.join(' ')} > ${name}_gen_fileList.txt
echo ${stat_files.join(' ')} > ${name}_stat_fileList.txt
"""
```

Once you are sure that `echo` above is printing as you expect, then you can do other stuff in that `process` block

Comment: Thanks `@user10101904`.  I am getting only the last chunk in the output *txt file. I tried to use `echo ${gen_files.join(' ')} >> ${name}_gen_fileList.txt` but same output. Also, I am getting an error: `WARN: failed to publish file` . The other processes work fine and gave no such kind of wrning.

Comment: I modified the `input` declaration a bit `tuple val("${chrom}"),path("${chrom}.*") into imputed.groupTuple().collect{chrom, files -> [ chrom, files.collect{it.string()}.join(' ')]}` which gave a new error: `input tuple does not match input set cardinality declared by process 'merging'`. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your actual code that generates the snippet you show

Without looking at your code, I would suggest that you could try this http://nextflow-io.github.io/patterns/index.html#_process_per_file_range

Comment: Hi, Thanks you. The link you shared does not help in this particular case as it is a output from a process. However, I have added the actual code that generates those chunks. Hope it clarifies the issue. Again, Thanks.