# Merge multiple output chunks to one file in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have a nextflow process that outputs multiple files, like below:

```
[chr1,/path/to/chr1_chunk1.TC.linear]
[chr1,/path/to/chr1_chunk1.HDL.linear]
[chr1,/path/to/chr1_chunk2.TC.linear]
[chr1,/path/to/chr1_chunk2.HDL.linear]
.....
```

The above example I got after using `transpose()` operator.

Now, I want to concatenate All chunks and all chromosome together ordered by chunk and chromosome number so that I get 1 file for TC and another file for HDL. I have multiple traits in many chunks so this link wouldn't be helpful. [output files (chromosomal chunks) merging in nextflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591229/output-files-chromosomal-chunks-merging-in-nextflow/68271631#68271631)
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the `branch` and `collectFile` operators. Look at the following directory structure below (where the .linear files have their names as contents):

```
➜  sandbox tree .
.
├── ex1.HDL.linear
├── ex1.TC.linear
├── ex2.HDL.linear
├── ex2.TC.linear
├── ex3.HDL.linear
├── ex3.TC.linear
└── example.nf
```

I wrote the following minimal reproducible example:

```
workflow {
  files = Channel.fromPath('**.linear', checkIfExists: true)
  files
    .branch {
      TC: it.name.contains('TC')
      HDL: it.name.contains('HDL')
    }
    .set { result }
  result
    .TC
    .collectFile(name: 'TC.txt', storeDir: '/Users/mribeirodantas/sandbox')
  result
    .HDL
    .collectFile(name: 'HDL.txt', storeDir: '/Users/mribeirodantas/sandbox')
}
```

After running this pipeline with `nextflow run example.nf`, I will get in the `/Users/mribeirodantas/sandbox` folder two new files: `TC.txt` and `HDL.txt`. The content of `TC.txt`, for example, is:

```
ex2.TC.linear
ex3.TC.linear
ex1.TC.linear
```

Answer (score 2):

If your chunk files are sufficiently small, you can use the [collectFile](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collectfile) operator to concatenate them into files with names defined using a dynamic grouping criteria:

> The grouping criteria is specified by a [closure](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#script-closure) that must return a
> pair in which the first element defines the file name for the group
> and the second element the actual value to be appended to that file.

To sort by chromosome number and then by chunk number, you can use the [toSortedList](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#tosortedlist) and [flatMap](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#flatmap) operators to feed the sorted collection into the [collectFile](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#collectfile) operator:

```
input_ch
    .map { key, chunk_file ->
        def matcher = chunk_file.name =~ /^chr(\d+)_chunk(\d+)\.(\w+)\.linear$/
        def (_, chrom, chunk, trait) = matcher[0]

        tuple( (chrom as int), (chunk as int), trait, chunk_file )
    }
    .toSortedList( { a, b -> (a[0] <=> b[0]) ?: (a[1] <=> b[1]) } )
    .flatMap()
    .collectFile( sort: false ) { chrom, chunk, trait, chunk_file ->
          [ "${trait}.linear", chunk_file.text ]
    }
```